# Why is javascript detecting I've scrolled to the bottom of element when I haven't?

Tags: javascript

I have checked other posts as well as documentation for JS, and this should be working, yet... the console.log fires immediately before I ever even scroll.

Any ideas?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zfym8g2f/

```js
var element = document.getElementById('plugin');
if (element.scrollHeight - element.scrollTop === element.clientHeight)
    {
        // element is at the end of its scroll, load more content
        console.log('scrolled');
    }
```

```css
#plugin {
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="plugin">test</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console.log it fires immediately because the condition from the if statement is true.

You need also to add the scroll event listener, like this:

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0383hfrL/

```
var element = document.getElementById('plugin');

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  if ((window.scrollY + window.innerHeight - element.offsetTop) > element.clientHeight - 150) {
    // element is at the end of its scroll, load more content
        console.log('scrolled');
  }
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Boom, beastmode. Thanks so much! I'm still learning a lot about JS as a whole, so it's little things like this that help me out a ton in just understanding it all around.

Comment: I'm glad it helped!